# Manual and Automatic Door closing

Tags: doors

Google is useless. I can't believe I am the only one out there looking for this solution. I want to be able to open and close my home and truck doors, normally as in manually with my hands, but I also want to be able to CLOSE (only) the door with a fob or a remote. Several car companies offer this, auto open and close rear hatches that can also be used normally. Linear actuators wont work, they offer automation only, and manual actuation would ruin the motors.

How is this done? All I need is to install it myself.

Comment: Home door as in garage door or front door?

Comment: If you only need the closing to be done, without a lot of parts/motors, look into screen door closer.   Might need beefier model than for common screen doors.  Don't even need a fob or remote.  Forget screen doors, look at commercial door closer.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say the solutions for a _structure_ door and a _vehicle_ door are going to be quite rather different... We could probably handle the _structure_ question here if you focus in more detail than that. I'd suggest asking about your truck door over at [mechanics.se] or, more likely, at a car customizer/tuner dedicated forum. There are plenty of people who have done this to their cars.